# Is it safe to keep speakers behind a monitor

Tags: display, audio, lcd, speakers, security

Currently my Computer is kept on a small table. The Speakers are kept behind my monitor (LCD). 
So is it safe to play a song or something on high volume (with high bass) ? Will it affect my LCD ?

My speaker:

[image]

Comment: It'd sound better if they were infront of the monitor ;)

Comment: I'd suggest to put the subwoofer on the floor, if possible. It is by far the most powerful of the three, and man's ear can't determine where the bass sound comes from, anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds as if you're afraid the vibration from the bass of the speaker will damage something.  The answer kind of depends on your speakers.  From your description, it sounds as if they're standard small PC speakers, which would probably not be able to induce that much vibration in the monitor.  If you have a meter-tall woofer back there, all bets are off, though.

For a better answer, edit your question to give more details about your setup.

EDIT: many PC speakers I've seen in the past few years have a hole on the back to allow wall-mounting.  Perhaps you could mount the speakers on the wall either beside or above the monitor, improving audio and also eliminating your nervousness.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no holes behind the speaker

Comment: @SBSP: you might want to consider hanging a small shelf on the wall.  Cost would be a few dollars and ten minutes in most situations and you could have the speakers where you want them.

Answer (score 17):

It should have no effect whatsoever.

TFTs, unlike CRT monitors, don't use magnetism in their operation.

Answer (score 8):

Speakers have big magnets in them, and in the old days CRT monitors used to use magnets to control the cathode ray gun in back.  Putting *good* speakers right next to a monitor resulted in problems (the cheap speakers that sometimes mounted directly to the side of a display were just that: cheap, with small magnets).

These days, it's just not an issue as LCD monitors have no use for magnets on their own and no parts that might be effected by a small magnetic force.

Comment: Even then, that was only true if the monitor was not shielded or if the speakers’ magnets were strong enough and in a position to directly affect the front of the screen itself.

Comment: Big speakers would also erase your credit cards if you set a wallet on one. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Only experience will tell.  At sufficiently high volume, you may cause some sort of resonance failure.  Like Matt said though, magnetism shouldn't be an issue.